# Интернационализация кода на Python

Tags: python, интернационализация, gettext

Занимаюсь интернационализацией проекта на Python. Это обычное приложение (не веб). Использую модуль gettext.

Интернационализация требуется в произвольных пакетах приложения, потенциально в любом.

Нужно иметь возможность изменять язык во время исполнения программы. Изменение может быть затребовано из любого модуля, при этом язык должен изменяться во всей программе.

Требуется только перевод строк, только в юникодные строки. Интернационализация числовых значений не учитывается.

Каким образом это лучше всего реализовать?

---

Использование `gettext.install` мне не подходит, потому что я не нашёл, как можно задать свой язык при вызове.

Можно изменить язык с использованием внешних переменных (`LANGUAGE` и т.п.) и отдельного вызова `gettext.install`, но это не подходит, так как на эти переменные могут быть завязаны другие приложения

Answer (score 3):

Перебрав некоторое количество вариантов решения задачи, остановился на следующем.

Создан модуль localization.py со следующим содержимым:

```
import contextlib
import gettext

DOMAIN = 'my_localization'
LOCALE_DIR = 'locale'

_translator = None

EN = ('en', )
RU = ('ru', ) + EN

DEFAULT_LANG = EN


def get_translator():
    global _translator
    if _translator is None:
        _translator = _Translator(DOMAIN, LOCALE_DIR, DEFAULT_LANG)
    return _translator


class _Translator(object):
    def __init__(self, domain, locale_dir, start_lang):
        self._domain = domain
        self._locale_dir = locale_dir
        self._lang = start_lang
        self._translation = self._get_translation(self._lang)

    def _get_translation(self, lang):
        return gettext.translation(self._domain, self._locale_dir, languages=lang, fallback=True)

    @property
    def lang(self):
        return self._lang

    @lang.setter
    def lang(self, new_lang):
        if self._lang == new_lang:
            return
        self._lang = new_lang
        self._translation = self._get_translation(new_lang)

    def __call__(self, message):
        return self._translation.ugettext(message)


@contextlib.contextmanager
def change_language(new_lang):
    old_lang = _translator.lang
    _translator.lang = new_lang
    yield
    _translator.lang = old_lang


get_translator()
```

В этом модуле есть глобальная переменная `_translator`, в которую сохраняется функция, осуществляющая перевод строки. Переменная инициализируется в момент загрузки модуля с помощью вызова функции `get_translator`.

С помощью констант уровня модуля `EN`, `RU` задаются языки и порядки использования файлов перевода для них. Эти константы предполагается использовать для свойства `lang` объекта, сохранённого в переменной `_translator`.

Константа `DEFAULT_LANG` используется для задания языка, используемого для перевода сразу после инициализации библиотеки.

Функция `get_translator` контролирует доступ к переменной `_translator` и инициализирует её при первом обращении.

Объект класса `_Translator` представляет собой функтор, преобразующий строку на нужный язык. Для указания языка используется свойство `lang`. При создании объекта и изменении языка вызывается функция `gettext.translation`. Для перевода сообщения используется вызов функции `ugettext`.

Функция `change_language` в комплекте с оператором `with` позволяет временно изменять используемый модулем язык перевода.

Для использования модуля нужно его импортировать и сохранить результат вызова функции `get_translator` в переменной. Использовать эту переменную как функцию, передавая сообщения, требующие перевода.

Comment: Конструкции как в get_translator можно сильно упростить, если использовать functools.cache или functools.lru_cache (добавляем кэширующий декоратор и оставляем в функции только `return _Translator(DOMAIN, LOCALE_DIR, DEFAULT_LANG)`)